# Node.js Client-Server Game, Should server be running a loop?

Tags: node.js, synchronization, game-engine

I got my first node.js demo working which allows multiple people to control a character on the same html canvas.  A character appears at the top left that you can use the arrow keys to walk around.

Since I am just sending input to the server and then relaying it out to all clients without doing anything else I ended up realizing that the clients get out of sync easily.

I did a lot of reading about synchronizing network games but there is something that is confusing me a bit.  From what I understand the game should be running on the server, and should be sending "snapshots" to the clients of the state of the game.

Where I'm getting confused at here is on the server's part.  Should the server be running the actual game as far as drawing out everything on a canvas? or just doing everything except draw, only running updates and then emitting the game state every X amount of milliseconds?

On my client end I am using requestAnimationFrame for the loop. If the case is the server just runs a loop with the game logic do I just try to match requestAnimationFrame with setInterval on the server?  This is the part that's really throwing me off. How should I go about creating the game loop on the Server?

Thank you for taking the time to look at this